# CircleCI 2.1 build failing

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am having some issues setting up my CircleCI `config.yml` file to accommodate a Cypress e2e test after I upgraded it to version 2.1. It keeps failing with the following error:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:
# [#/jobs/build] 0 subschemas matched instead of one
# 1. [#/jobs/build] only 1 subschema matches out of 2
# |   1. [#/jobs/build] 2 schema violations found
# |   |   1. [#/jobs/build] extraneous key [branches] is not permitted
# |   |   |   Permitted keys:
# |   |   |     - description
# |   |   |     - parallelism
# |   |   |     - macos
# |   |   |     - resource_class
# |   |   |     - docker
# |   |   |     - steps
# |   |   |     - working_directory
# |   |   |     - machine
# |   |   |     - environment
# |   |   |     - executor
# |   |   |     - shell
# |   |   |     - parameters
# |   |   |   Passed keys:
# |   |   |     - working_directory
# |   |   |     - docker
# |   |   |     - steps
# |   |   |     - branches
# |   |   2. [#/jobs/build/docker/0] extraneous key [env] is not permitted
# |   |   |   Permitted keys:
# |   |   |     - image
# |   |   |     - name
# |   |   |     - entrypoint
# |   |   |     - command
# |   |   |     - user
# |   |   |     - environment
# |   |   |     - aws_auth
# |   |   |     - auth
# |   |   |   Passed keys:
# |   |   |     - image
# |   |   |     - env
# 2. [#/jobs/build] expected type: String, found: Mapping
# |   Job may be a string reference to another job
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
```

This is my yml file:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/myapp-web
    docker:
      - image: node:10.13.0-stretch
        env:
          - DISPLAY=:99
          - CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: |
            npm install -g @angular/cli
            npm install
            npm install -g firebase-tools
            apt-get -y -qq update
            apt-get -y -qq install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
            if [[ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
              apt-get -y -qq update
              apt-get -y -qq install python-dev
              curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
              python get-pip.py --user
              echo 'export PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile 
              source ~/.bash_profile
              pip install awscli --upgrade --user
              ~/.local/bin/aws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4
            fi
            cd /root/myapp-web/src/app/functions/ && npm install
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command:
            npm run test-headless
      - run:
          name: Deploy to AWS
          command: |
            if [[ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
              ng build --prod --configuration=production --progress=false
              ~/.local/bin/aws --region eu-west-2 s3 sync /root/myapp-web/dist/myapp-web/ s3://$AWS_BUCKET_TARGET --delete --exclude '.git/*'
            fi
      - run:
          name: Deploy to Firebase
          command: |
            cd /root/myapp-web/src/app/functions/
            if [[ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
              firebase use myapp-dev
            fi
            if [[ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
              firebase use myapp-live
            fi
            firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
    branches:
      only:
        - develop
        - master
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
workflows:
  test_then_build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          start: npm run serve
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:4200'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the location where you are filtering branch is wrong. You should filter branches in workflow and not in jobs. Also not worked with orbs, so I'm not sure of the orbs location also.

```
branches:
  only:
    - develop
    - master
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help: https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015953868-Filter-branches-for-jobs-and-workflows

You can only filter branches in jobs if you have only one job and you aren't use the `workflows` keyword.
i.e.

```
jobs:  
  build:  
    branches:  
      only:  
        - master  
        - /rc-.*/
```

Otherwise you need to use it like so with `workflows`:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
    build:
      jobs:
        - test:
            filters:
              branches:
                only:
                  - master
```